# Internal Server Error using WAMP server

Tags: php, .htaccess, wamp

I've created a `MVC` application using `php`,  but when I try to access the urls it gives me "The server encountered an internal error"

When I check the log it gives me :

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
> Please contact the server administrator at admin@example.com to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

my `.htaccess` file Code:

```
Options-MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase/MVC/public

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f


RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Make sure mod_rewrite is ON in your apache setting

Comment: Which log? Have you checked the event log in Windows and the errorlog in Apache?

Comment: @ amit how to On mod_rewrite am new in php

Comment: @anubhava not working

Comment: Check your Apache error.log for actual error message.

Comment: @anubhava in my Apache error.log Message  C:/wamp/www/MVC/app/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Options-Indexes', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: You need to always have a space after `Options` word. So it should be `Options -Indexes`

Comment: I have this what it is C:/wamp/www/MVC/public/.htaccess: Invalid command 'RewriteEngine', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration can any one help

Comment: I got Answer Thanks For Help guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable mod_rewrite, went through the below steps:

```
1. Find and open the file .http.conf. This will be located in your Apache install folder.
2. Make a backup of http.conf which you can restore from, if anything were to go wrong
3. Find the line #LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so and remove the hash ‘#’
4. Locate the block within the directory tags as indicated below and change to:
<directory />
Options All
AllowOverride All
</directory>
5. Find any additional occurrences of the line “AllowOverride None” and change it to “AllowOverride All”.
6.Finally, restart apache server and your browser. The .htaccess rewriting should now be working for any local website.
```

Comment: C:/wamp/www/MVC/app/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Options-Indexes', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Comment: Also make sure mod_rewrite is ON.
create test.php file with code <?php phpinfo(); ?>
execute it and see mod_rewirite is on or off

Comment: my apache version is 2.4.9

Answer (score 4):

This problem comes due to wampserver using local.

You can change it with:

- Left click on wampsever
- Go to APACHE -> APACHE MODULES
- scroll down and find "rewrite_module"
- Then mark it check

It will restart automatically. All set.

Comment: @HebeleHododo I have tried it but its not working. Still facing the same error

Comment: @HebeleHododo, try stop all services and restart again

Answer (score 4):

This problem is faced in Wampserver when the essential modules are not enable

You can Enable them with:

- Left click on Wampsever icon
- Go to APACHE -> APACHE MODULES
- scroll down and find "rewrite_module" and "headers_module"
- Then mark them check

It will restart automatically. Done.

[image]